# Is it possible to bind the foreground color of any textcontrol

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

So I've been trying to figure this out for 3 days and I just can't seem to find a solution.

This is what I am trying to achieve.
I have a simple WPF project with a `RichTextBox` in it.
What my application is doing is that it acts like a CMD.

What I want to do now is that I want to change the message it saved when I press enter, I want the previous message to change color.

Here is a GIF showing what it looks like
https://i.imgur.com/srszUKG.gifv

I tried binding the `Foreground` of the `TextBox` inside the `DataTemplate` but that just made it to where the text wouldnt even show up.

```
<DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" Foreground="White" Name="SavedBlocks" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

So what are my options here, I essentially want to change the color of the text depending on how long the message is.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1Eh.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1Eh"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Name="Scroller" Margin="0" Background="Black">
            <StackPanel>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConsoleOutput, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" Foreground="White" Name="SavedBlocks" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ConsoleInput, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Black" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Consolas" Name="InputBlock" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionBrush="{x:Null}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

main.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ConsoleContent dc = new ConsoleContent();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded1;
            DataContext = dc;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InputBlock.KeyDown += InputBlock_KeyDown;
            InputBlock.Focus();
        }

        void InputBlock_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                dc.ConsoleInput = InputBlock.Text;
                dc.RunCommand();
                InputBlock.Focus();
                Scroller.ScrollToBottom();

            }
        }
    }
```

ConsoleContent.cs

```
public class ConsoleContent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string consoleInput = string.Empty;
    ObservableCollection<string> consoleOutput = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Console Emulation Sample..." };

    public string ConsoleInput
    {
        get
        {
            return consoleInput;
        }
        set
        {
            consoleInput = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ConsoleInput");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ConsoleOutput
    {
        get
        {
            return consoleOutput;
        }
        set
        {
            consoleOutput = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ConsoleOutput");
        }
    }

    public void RunCommand()
    {
        ConsoleOutput.Add(ConsoleInput);
        //myBrush = Brushes.Orange;
        // do your stuff here.
        ConsoleInput = String.Empty;
    }



    private System.Windows.Media.Brush _foregroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.DarkSeaGreen;

    public System.Windows.Media.Brush ForegroundColor
    {
        get { return _foregroundColor; }
        set
        {
            _foregroundColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ForegroundColor");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Change ObservableCollection<string> to ObservableCollection<YourType> and set and bind to a Foreground property on YourType?

Comment: @mm8 But then it would just print out this, i feel like I need to print the property of the class and it seems like its printing the class now https://i.imgur.com/szgMM85.png

Comment: Of course, the data template needs to be updated for this type.

Comment: On your own type, you should override the `ToString` method to return the property value.

Comment: @NerdzIT: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of `consoleOutput` from `ObservableCollection<string>` to `ObservableCollection<YourType>` where `YourType` is a class that represents a line of input with a text `string` and a Foreground `Brush`:

```
public class YourType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); }
    }

    private Brush _foreground;
    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return _foreground; }
        set { _foreground = value; OnPropertyChanged("Foreground"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Bind to the properties of this class in your XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="Scroller" Margin="0" Background="Black">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConsoleOutput, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" 
                               Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" 
                               Name="SavedBlocks" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ConsoleInput, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Black" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Consolas" Name="InputBlock" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionBrush="{x:Null}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

You can then set the `Foreground` property of each individual item in the source collection:

```
public void RunCommand()
{
    ConsoleOutput.Add(new YourType { Text = ConsoleInput, Foreground = Brushes.Orange } );
    ConsoleInput = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: That makes alot of sense! Thank you!